# How to know if Octave (GUI) is busy/running

Tags: octave, octave-gui

It is a simple issue, but unfortunately I couldn't find the answer in any previous question. Currently, I am using Octave-6.4.0 (GUI) for simulating simple models, although I am more used to work with Matlab. Therefore, I found it really useful that Matlab shows the state "Ready" or "Busy" in the bottom-left bar. Is there something similar in Octave to check if the model has finished or if it is still running?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I will add that if you think this >> indicator is insufficient, you could create a wishlist bug report over at bugs.octave.org.  It will probably be low priority, but there's been a bit of work on the gui and interpreter recently, so it might get some interest.

Answer (score 1):

The markers `>>` indicating that you can write a new command will only appear after the current simulation is finished.

From [Tasos Papastylianou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4183191/tasos-papastylianou)'s comment:

> More usefully, you might consider printing logs every now and then
> during your simulation, to keep track of progress (every million
> iterations, for example, or something along those lines)